# Shopware 6 - best practice needed for how to deal with different delivery times

Tags: shopware6

I would love to sell the same product in different countries but with obvious also different delivery times. Now as I know I am only able to set one value at the product. If I switch through the languages the same value gets translated but I am not able to set another value for France and Germany if you get the picture.

deliverytime

[image: 1]

Now I would like to ask how to properly deal with different times like 1-2 days in Germany vs. 2-4 days for France.

Answer (score 1):

The delivery time is an entity and the association to said entity isn't conditional to the sales channel at this time. Your best bet is to change the label of the delivery time depending on the language. Under `Settings > Shop > Delivery times` in the administration you can change the language and set a different label for each language. So for `English` you could have it say "5 - 10 days" and for `Deutsch` it could be "1 - 3 days". The `Minimum` and `Maximum` fields unfortunately aren't translatable as of today. Maybe it is an option to take the minimum und maximum values between all the translated labels, so in this example `Minimum` would be `1` and `Maximum` would be `10`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but i really would like to avoid cheese technics. With just translation changes i would loose the chance to set different delivery times for different products (because the en-translation for the german 1-3 days would now always be 5-10 days if i understand your suggestion correctly) I have the same issues with something like making different products for every sales channel. In the options i can see clearly the system wants me to make different entities for every delivery case like 1-2 days vs. 2-4days. I am worried

Comment: Well the `deliveryTime` field is a `ManyToOneAssociationField`. You just simply can't assign multiple `delivery_time` entities to one `product`. The `delivery_time` itself also has no association to `sales_channel` or `language` to distinguish which one to fetch. You'd have to [extend the product definition](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities) with your own `ManyToManyAssociationField` to `delivery_time`. Then you'd have to provide the logic to use that association instead yourself too. No short answer here.

Comment: I understand. This isn't the answer i had expected but thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Sorry for the answer being disappointing at this time. Just so you know, we are aware of the need for this functionality and are working on a solution.